# determining the start velocity and angle based on the goals(End point) angle and coordinates.

Tags: derivatives, conic-sections

========

I'm trying to figure out the **start angle** and **velocity** of an parabola, **When i know only the start coordinates and the end point coordinates and the angle which it reaches the endpoint.**

I'm tasked with figuring this out by using derivative method.

So the known parameters are:
Start point (0,0)
end point (6,4)
end point angle (-18)

unknown are:
velocity = unknown.
start angle =unkown.

This is a homework assiment thats been bothering me for months now.

Here is a picture of what i've been working with:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is gravity acting along the vertical, in the picture? It doesn't look so. And it doesn't even look like a parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of motion of a projectile starting from the origin, and shot at an angle $\theta $ above the horizon, at an initial velocity $\mathbf{v_0}$ is

$\mathbf{P}(t) = \mathbf{v_0} t + \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{g} t^2 $

Now, $\mathbf{P}(t) = ( x(t), y(t) ) $ and $\mathbf{v_0} = v_0 (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) $, and $ \mathbf{g} = (0, - g ) $ , where $g = 9.81 \ \text{m/s}^2$

Hence,

$ x(t) = v_0 \ cos (\theta) \ t  $

$ y(t) = v_0 \ \sin(\theta) \ t - \dfrac{1}{2} \ g \ t^2 $

Solving for $t$ from the first equation for $x(t)$,

$ t = \dfrac{x}{v_0 \cos \theta} $

Substitute this into the equation for $y(t)$

$ y = \tan(\theta) \ x - \dfrac{g \ x^2}{2 v_0^2 \cos^2(\theta)  }\hspace{25pt} (1) $

Substitute the point $(6, 4)$ into equation $(1)$

$ 4 = 6 \tan(\theta) - \dfrac{ 18 g }{ v_0^2 \cos^2 \theta } \hspace{25pt} (2)$

Differentiate equation $(1)$ with respect to $x$ to get the slope of the tangent to the projectile trajectory,

$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \tan(\phi) = \tan(\theta) - \dfrac{ g x }{ v_0^2 \cos^2 \theta } \hspace{25pt} (3) $

Since at the end point (which is $(6, 4)$) the angle is $\phi = -18^\circ$, then substituting this into $(3)$, gives us

$ \tan(-18^\circ) = \tan(\theta) - \dfrac{ 6 g }{ v_0^2 \cos^2 \theta } \hspace{25pt}(4)$

Eliminating the second term from equations $(2)$ and $(4)$, we get

$ 4 - 3 \tan(-18^\circ) = 3 \tan(\theta) $

Hence, $ \theta = \tan^{-1}\bigg( \dfrac{ 4 - 3 \tan(-18^\circ) }{3} \bigg) = 58.9^\circ$

Substitute this into $(2)$ and solve for $v_0$,

$ v_0 = \sqrt{ \dfrac{18 g }{ (6 \tan(\theta) - 4) \cos^2(\theta) } } = 10.55 \ \text{m/s}$

Comment: Hi ! Based on my teacher. With launch point of **0,0** and end point of **5,3**, end angle of **-20**. The starting velocity should be **9.633** and start angle of **57.4052**. Sorry to bother you, but ive searched the internet about this and cant figure a way to calculate the right answer. Thank you for your help. Your calcucation of the starting angle was spot on!

Comment: I did similar calculations to the ones in the solution above, and got $\theta = 57.4052^\circ$ and $v_0 = 9.4536 \ \text{m/s}^2 $